# Запущена ли уже функция jquery

Tags: jquery, функции, javascript

Можно ли узнать была ли ранее запущена функция в jquery? есть способ кроме глобальной переменой?

Comment: пишите в куку кол-во запусков функции.

Comment: @naym, идея

Comment: Зачем заморачиваться с куками? Можно так, если я Вас правильно понял: http://jsfiddle.net/a7mmR/

Comment: @Павел Азанов так я умею. мне интересно есть ли способ без переменой

Comment: @M11 кука по сути ещё более глобальная переменная. можно не глобальные переменную создавать, а переменную в родительской области видимости.

http://jsfiddle.net/a7mmR/1/

@Павел Азанов, в this конечно, так лучше не писать :)